# Little issue with JDeveloper & Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, jdeveloper

I have the followinf issue in running Vaadin in JDeveloper. I opened NetBeans and install the corresponding plug-in and ran the example and it worked all ok. So then, I copy the same project structure to a JDeveloper project but, when I try to run the project I am asked to set a "Default Run Target" which I don't know how to do... The starting point should be Vaadin Servlet but how to do If I am ask to select a file...

Hope someone knows how to solve this... Cheers from Argentina...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hitting run on your project - select a specific page in your application that you want to run in the application navigator, right click on it and choose run.
Or just select a specific JSF/JSP/Servlet that you want to run when prompted.

Comment: Thankx you for answering me... Well... Vaadin as far as I know, doesn't use pages... The Registered Vaadin Servlet has an init param which is a class where you set up all the components... I installed the Vaadin plugin in NB and click run in the project and all went Ok... Going straight to the point, when I am asked to select a default run target I am only able to select a fail not specify the package where the Vaadin Servlet is... So I can't do much... I am working with ADF and because I am use to this IDE, I would like to see if this works...  Thankx again